# Extricating table based on the first unique column value

Tags: python, shell, awk

I have a large file (2 GB)which is in tabular format and I need to grep based on  the first value from the second column

```
Ref1    xzxzxzz00000135960.1    51.74   259 125 0   1   259 125 383 3e-85   269
Ref1    xzxzxzz00000126626.2    50.20   249 124 0   11  259 2   250 8e-79   248
Ref1    xzxzxzz00000137335.1    49.81   259 130 0   1   259 125 383 1e-78   252
Ref1    ASNP00000445420.1   49.42   259 131 0   1   259 125 383 3e-78   251
Ref1    xzxzxzz00000126626.2    52.20   349 124 0   11  259 2   250 8e-79   248
Ref1    ASNP00000445420.1   49.80   255 128 0   1   255 125 379 2e-77   249
Ref1    ASNPCAP00000013746.1    47.88   259 135 0   1   259 106 364 1e-76   243
Ref2    xzxzxzz00000108341.3    26.38   163 87  8   11  140 156 318 5e-04   43.9
Ref2    ASNP00000026303.9   26.38   163 87  8   11  140 149 311 5e-04   43.9
Ref2   xzxzxzz00000108321.3    16.38   163 87  8   11  140 156 318 5e-04   43.9
Ref2    ASNP00000108340.1   26.38   163 87  8   11  140 149 311 5e-04   43.9
Ref2    ENSLAFP00000015342.3    25.45   165 86  9   11  140 150 312 0.002   41.6
```

I need to get the first unique alphabets from the second column with respect to first column value Expected output like this

```
Ref1    xzxzxzz00000135960.1    51.74   259 125 0   1   259 125 383 3e-85   269
Ref1    ASNP00000445420.1   49.42   259 131 0   1   259 125 383 3e-78   251
Ref1    ASNPCAP00000013746.1    47.88   259 135 0   1   259 106 364 1e-76   243
Ref2    xzxzxzz00000108341.3    26.38   163 87  8   11  140 156 318 5e-04   43.9
Ref2    ASNP00000026303.9   26.38   163 87  8   11  140 149 311 5e-04   43.9
Ref2    ENSLAFP00000015342.3    25.45   165 86  9   11  140 150 312 0.002   41.6
```

I tried with R but failed due to the size (maybe the system configuration ). Any suggestion from python or AWK?

Comment: On SO we do encourage people to add their efforts in their post, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: I tried with awk with this command  'FNR==1{print;next} !a[substr($2,1,6)]++'   but it failed

Comment: OK good, please add that code in your post. Could you please explain more about logic of getting expected output? Like why `xzxzxzz00000126626.2` is not in output at least its 1 entry should be there right?

Comment: Idea is to get the first unique alphabets from the second column with respect to first column value

Comment: Describe clear the relation because it is very unclear what you want exactly

Comment: This data set is in sorted format and I need to grep first unique alphabets (which is having the highest value) based on the First column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following. This should be faster I believe though I haven't tested with huge data.

```
awk '
{
  val=$2
  gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]+/,"",val)
}
!a[$1,val]++{
  value=(value?value ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  print value
}
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Ref1    xzxzxzz00000135960.1    51.74   259 125 0   1   259 125 383 3e-85   269
Ref1    ASNP00000445420.1   49.42   259 131 0   1   259 125 383 3e-78   251
Ref1    ASNPCAP00000013746.1    47.88   259 135 0   1   259 106 364 1e-76   243
Ref2    xzxzxzz00000108341.3    26.38   163 87  8   11  140 156 318 5e-04   43.9
Ref2    ASNP00000026303.9   26.38   163 87  8   11  140 149 311 5e-04   43.9
Ref2    ENSLAFP00000015342.3    25.45   165 86  9   11  140 150 312 0.002   41.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Python version, using `re` module and `itertools.groupby`.

If `data.txt` is input from your question, then this script:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for v, g in groupby(f_in, lambda k: k.split()[0]):
        seen = set()
        for line in g:
            alpha = re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z]+', line.split()[1])[0]
            if alpha not in seen:
                seen.add(alpha)
                print(line.strip())
```

Produces:

```
Ref1    xzxzxzz00000135960.1    51.74   259 125 0   1   259 125 383 3e-85   269
Ref1    ASNP00000445420.1   49.42   259 131 0   1   259 125 383 3e-78   251
Ref1    ASNPCAP00000013746.1    47.88   259 135 0   1   259 106 364 1e-76   243
Ref2    xzxzxzz00000108341.3    26.38   163 87  8   11  140 156 318 5e-04   43.9
Ref2    ASNP00000026303.9   26.38   163 87  8   11  140 149 311 5e-04   43.9
Ref2    ENSLAFP00000015342.3    25.45   165 86  9   11  140 150 312 0.002   41.6
```